# Self vs return in Python Classes for Class Attribute

Tags: python, oop, self

Suppose I have a class attribute in the form of list, and two functions inside that class that append data onto the list for further operations on the list.

Would this be a proper way to write the same:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Mylist = []
        self.customfunc1()
        self.customfunc2()
        self.customfunc3()

    def customfunc1(self):
        somevar = 1
        self.Mylist.append(somevar)
    
    def customfunc2(self):
        somevar = 2
        self.Mylist.append(somevar)

    def customFunc3(self):
        ## Operations on self.Mylist
```

Or Do I need to return a value after every sub function. I'm new to using 'self' reference so any help appreciated.

Comment: It just not related to each other, self is a reference to the class, so if you want that after using your funcs the user will get the modified list you can return it. If not - dont. Most of times when writing `set` functions usually don't return the modified member

Comment: @YossiLevi so in the example I showed above , its kinda okay to write it like that?

Comment: I think that's the way I would do it, when the user is set value to inner member, he usually don't expect to get it back

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the intend. When you look, for example, at the standard library (`list.append`), the convention is that when a method mutates its argument, it does not return anything (i.e. it implicitly returns `None`). The idea is to make it really obvious that the data was changed.

If, other other hand, the data does not change but you create a new instance, then, well, you don't really have any other option that to return the new instance.

For you example, it is a bit hard to tell as it is a bit artificial but since `MyList` is an internal implementation detail of the class, I would definitely not return (or the value).

PS: In your example, there are only "instance variables", not "class attribute[s]" - for that the fields would have to be declared one scope above.

Comment: Yes , my bad ,what I meant was mylist is a variable in which data is inserted through the functions below init method and then used in the third subfunction.The way I wrote it, included not returning but using self as it is.Just wanted to know if I dont need the variable instead of just returning could I pass it as I have done above?

Comment: "class variable" would mean in your example that the data is global, that's probably not what you wanted. In any case, I would not return anything as it mutates the given instance.